# Firebase Auth: Re-authenticate user who is using custom token

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

In android app the user is allowed to use Linkedin as signin option using Firebase Functions. User sends linkedin token to firebase function and as a result it receives `AdminSdk` generated [Custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk).

Now as we know the token can be used for signin with
`mAuth.signInWithCustomToken(mCustomToken)`. But I cannot find a way to use the custom token to generate `AuthCredential`.

There is [OAuthProvider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/OAuthProvider) class which can generate AuthCredential but re-authentication fails.
`getCredential(String providerId, String idToken, String accessToken)`

Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately Firebase Auth does not offer a way to re-authenticate with a custom token. You can request this as a feature: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Right now, you have to basically use `signInWithCustomToken` again. However, you will be signing out the original user and there is also a risk the user signs in with a different account. You will need to retain the original `uid` to confirm the new signed in user is the same one (has same `uid`). If the same user signs in again, you also have to get a new reference to the currentUser.

Comment: I will be waiting for this feature to be added in firebase. I have already submitted the feature request.